# How to add JPanel Dynamically through Looping?

Tags: java, swing

Please I want to add `JPanel` dynamically through looping. i have tried calling the function like this:

```
public void Repeat() {
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       jPanel3.add(jPanel9);
   }
}
```

This is the source code for the Panel

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel12Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel12);
    jPanel12.setLayout(jPanel12Layout);
    jPanel12Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel12Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel12Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel12Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(jPanel12Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(14, 14, 14)
                    .addGroup(jPanel12Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel12Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel22)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 84, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel23))
                        .addGroup(jPanel12Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel24)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jLabel25)
                            .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                            .addComponent(jLabel26)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel27))
                        .addComponent(jSeparator3)))
                .addGroup(jPanel12Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8)))
            .addGap(14, 14, 14))
    );
    jPanel12Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel12Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel12Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel12Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel22)
                .addComponent(jLabel23))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jSeparator3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel12Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel12Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel12Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel25)
                        .addComponent(jLabel26)))
                .addComponent(jLabel27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel12Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 16, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(12, 12, 12))
    );

    jPanel9.add(jPanel12, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 119, 346, 100));
```

I have copied and pasted the code but it's not working
[This is the Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbd5x.jpg) 
Or Could there be other logic in adding `JPanel` dynamically

Comment: Can you specify what you want to do or can you add the full code here, don't worry about if it working.

Comment: One component can only have one parent, or, in other words, the same instance can only be added once - if it is added again, it will first be removed from previous container. A new instance must be created for/in each interaction of the loop.

Comment: @EbraheemAlrabee' i have just added the source code

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to add 10 same components inside a panel?
Be sure to check documentation regarding proper usage of panels and adding certain components inside one.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html

Answer (score 0):

No special logic needed. Just keep one Panel as a parent and add all the dynamic panel on it.

```
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
       JPanel childPanel = new JPanel();
       /**
         * This below line is not needed. Added here 
         * just to show different number to identify each panel.
         */
       childPanel.add(new JLabel("Number : " + i));

       mainPanel.add(childPanel);
    }

   // Add the main Panel in your frame.
    add(mainPanel);
```

Comment: I think you need post the actual code. I have tested this before posting it here. May be you are not adding the main panel properly.

Comment: You are adding same instance (jLabel9) nine times that doesn't make sense. instead of this(jPanel3.add(jPanel9), you need to add new instance of panel in your loop. something like this jPanel3.add(new JPanel());